# REST services design: cancel an order?

Tags: rest

Given order cancelling as a requirement, what is the best design option of representing this operation in RESTful way and why?

I can think at least of the following

- PUT `/orders/{id}/cancelled` (with an empty body)
- PUT `/orders/{id}` (with an entire order JSON/XML/etc with changed attribute `cancelled`)

Comment: What about `DELETE /orders/{id}`? I can't think of o more semantic alternative. Note, the operation doesn't _necessarily_ have to delete the order from the persistence layer.

Comment: You could also PATCH the order with `[{ "op": "replace", "path": "/cancelled", "value": true }]`. Cross-network dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141410/restful-state-changing-actions

Answer (score 9):

Take in mind that your resource should be a noun, not a verb or an adjective. Your `http` is responsible for telling what you are doing with the resource

1. `/orders/{id}/cancelation`

`PUT` - cancels order

`DELETE` - rolls back cancelation (might be a scenario as well)

`GET` - returns cancelation details (you may want to extend `cancelation` resource with `timestamp` and `username` fields for example)

2. `/orders/{id}`

PUT (PATCH) - it is okay to cancel by passing something like:

```
{
    ...
    "order_status": "CANCELLED"
    ...
}
```

It really depends on your business domain, but the first one sounds preferable for me because it adds some flexibility like extending model with `timestamp` and cancelation of cancelation.

Answer (score 0):

> Given order cancelling as a requirement, what is the best design option of representing this operation in RESTful way and why?

Think about how you would cancel an order on an website....

You would GET the order; within the representation of that order would be a link, with some semantic markup like `to cancel your order, click here`.  Following that link would bring you to a cancellation form, with controls representing the information that needs to be submitted, probably with default values provided.  You would then submit that form, and the response back would communicate the status of your attempt to cancel the order.

The right RESTful approach is to do that.  The key idea being that the representations provided by the server tell the client how to do; the client only needs to have advanced understanding of the protocol: what links to look for, what form semantics to look for.

(In short, what REST tells you to do is build a website for your integration domain, with machine readable representations of the application states.)

The why is that it allows the provider and the consumer to evolve independently; as long as the protocol between the two remains stable, you can change the underlying implementation of either as often as you like.

Comment: *"You would then submit that form, and the response back would communicate the status of your attempt to cancel the order."* The problem is that form does a `POST` to `CancelOrder.ashx` - which is not RESTful. So the question was: what **is** the REST approach?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using patch:
patch /api/resource
{cancelled:true}

Use patch for partial updates.